# A Proposition of Matrix over Complex Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Given $A^{n\times n}$ a complex matrix and $z=\begin{pmatrix} z_{1} \\ \vdots \\ z_{n} \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}$. Show that $\overline {A\cdot z}=\overline {A}\cdot \overline {z}$.  Note that $\overline {A}, \overline{z}$ means that conjugate of $A$ and $z$, respectively.

I showed for $2\times2$, $3\times3$ but how should I show for $n\times n$ because there are too many entires for this, can you help, can you give me a hint?

Comment: Suffices to prove that $\overline{uv}=\overline{u}\cdot\overline{v}$ for any complex numbers $u,v$.

Comment: But dont you also have to show $\overline{u+v}=\overline{u}+\overline{v}$ ???

Comment: You had a nice description of what you tried before; it would have been nice if you had left that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're fine working through the particular cases, but you have trouble generalizing to the $n \times n$ cases.

When you hit an obstacle like that, it's often a good idea to use summation notation.  In this particular case, we note that the $j$th entry of $Az$ is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n A_{jk}z_k
$$
That being said, we can rewrite the equality you're trying to prove as
$$
\overline{\sum_{k=1}^n A_{jk}z_k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \bar A_{jk}\bar z_k, \quad j=1,\dots,n
$$
I suspect that you'll be able to figure out the trick from there.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried to use induction on $n$ but it was very complicated.